# How to pass custom properties from single-spa-angularjs entry point to an angularjs main module?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, single-page-application

I'm using the single-spa library to combine my ReactJS and AngularJS applications into a SPA. ReactJS is a main app uses single-spa library to load AngularJS app, which has single-spa-angularjs library.

This is my AngularJS app-bootstrap.js entry point:

```html
import singleSpaAngularJS from 'single-spa-angularjs';
import angular from 'angular';

function domElementGetter() {
    let el = document.getElementById('angular');
    if (!el) {
        el = document.createElement('div');
        el.id = 'angular';
        document.body.appendChild(el);
    }

    return el;
}

const angularLifecycles = singleSpaAngularJS({
    angular: angular,
    domElementGetter,
    mainAngularModule: 'mainModule',
    uiRouter: true,
    preserveGlobal: false,
    strictDi: true,
});

export function bootstrap(props) {
    return angularLifecycles.bootstrap(props);
}

export function mount(props) {
    return angularLifecycles.mount(props);
}

export function unmount(props) {
    return angularLifecycles.unmount(props);
}
```

I'm able to pass some custom properties from the main ReactJS app to a child one, e.g. `export function bootstrap(props) {...` **props** object has my custom properties.

The question is **how can I pass these custom properties to my main module of AngularJS application?**

Thanks in advance for any help!